# defining the determinant of a matrix combined of function

Tags: determinant

I have the following question:
f1(x),....fn(x) belong to polynomial space with a degree less or equal to n-2
a1,....an belong to the real numbers.
what is the determinant of matrix A ?

[image]

Comment: Hint: The rows of your matrix are linearly dependent.

Comment: can you please add more?

Comment: The polynomials of degree $\leq n-2$ form an $n-1$-dimensional vector space. Hence, their lists of values at $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ also belong to an at-most-$n-1$-dimensional vector space. Thus, they are linearly dependent.

Comment: thank you! great